# Reinstalling Missing Shared libraries 16.04

Tags: uninstall, shared-library

- I'm using a third-party software called FSL, a neuroimaging tool.

  - I had to uninstall it with `sudo apt-get remove fsl`as well as `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove fsl`.
  - As a relative newbie, I entered it but after realized what is prompted me to delete, including linux kernel headers. Using `find fsl`command there was nothing left of fsl
  - I also used `locate fsl`and deleted everything I could that that command output.
  - A symptom is running `sudo apt-get update`doesn't seem to update anything as I can continuously run the command with the same output

Trying to reinstall I get `dpkg: warning: files list file for package '$FILE' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed`

I think I did quite a bit of damage to my computer and am not sure of all the files I deleted. Is there some way to find out which shared libraries are missing and reinstall them? Can someone help? Should I just reinstall ubuntu on my machine? Any help would be great.

Comment: Does it really say `'$FILE'` - or are you using that as shorthand for a bunch of different package names?

Comment: I'm using that as shorthand for any file. These files are specific to fsl